# MySQL Operational Error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to upload data into a MySQL database, but I am having trouble doing so. The error I receive when I try to run my code is `2003, Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db_host' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)`. Does anyone know what this error means or how to fix it?  I have included my code below.

```
import pymysql
import time
import good_morning as gm

DB_HOST = 'db_host'
DB_USER = 'db_user'
DB_PASS = 'db_pass'
DB_NAME = 'db_name'

conn = pymysql.connect(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER, passwd=DB_PASS, db=DB_NAME)

kr = gm.KeyRatiosDownloader()
fd = gm.FinancialsDownloader()
kr_frames = kr.download('AAPL', conn)
fd_frames = fd.FinancialsDownloader()
```

Comment: Do you ***really*** have a host named db_host ?   Typically that would be replaced with an IP address or even possibly localhost. Same with the other DB_* related parameters that should have realistic values.

Comment: No I don't think so, but I borrowed the code from an example online that seemed to work for that person.  Can I just use .connect()?  Or how else should I go about creating a MySQL database?  Thanks for your advice.

Comment: The "borrowed code" has very likely replaced those values with that info so as NOT to expose their own (which is typical). So, first you need to replace all the `db_*` values to match your config. Try starting with this first.